# R hexbin: Get count for particular bin

Tags: r

Suppose I create a hexbin (using the [hexbin package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hexbin/index.html)):

```
h <- hexbin(df)
```

where df has x and y fields.  For a particular value of x and y, how do I get the count of the corresponding bin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
get_count <- function(x, y, h) {
  my_dist <- function(x2, y2) {
    return(sqrt((x - x2) ^ 2 + (y - y2) ^ 2))
  }

  distances <- mapply(my_dist, attr(h, 'xcm'), attr(h, 'ycm'))

  return(attr(h, 'count')[which.min(distances)])
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are using the hexbin function from `library(hexbin)` you can use the bin IDs to achive what you want.

Call the function as `hexbin(..., IDs = T)` and the result will have a field that tells you in which bin the points fall.

Working example:

```
library(hexbin)

x <- c(1, 1.2, 1, 3, 5, -2 ,1, 0, 0.8)
y <- c(1, 1, 0, -1, 0, 2, -1, 1, 1)

h <- hexbin(x, y, xbins = 3,IDs = T)

#what is the cell ID of point 1?
ID1 <- h@cID[1]

#how many points fall in that cell?
sum(h@cID == ID1) #answer is 4 in this case
```